# how can I append None values from file to list in Python

Tags: python, list, append, nonetype

I have Json file that want to save some attributes in lists. One attribute has some values and sometimes has `None` values (there is no data). When I used `append()`, it appended only values, and ignore `None` values.

I need to read None values too. How can I do it

json like:

```
{ "A":1,
  "B":2,
  "C":3}

{ "A":4,
  "B":,
  "C":2}

{ "A":4,
  "B":1,
  "C":2}

{ "A":4,
  "B":,
  "C":5}
```

If I want to save B in list, I need it like B = [2,None,1,None], but the result I have is [2,1]

I saved json file to object using `json.loads()` and there is no problem with it.

i did like that:

```
for line in json_file:
    query.append(line['B'])
```

Comment: So, use the conditional statement: `if attribute != None: ...append(attribute)`.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: What is the result of your json.loads() ?

Comment: When I try to reproduce your issue, json.loads fails entirely with a ValueError because of the undefined values.  If they are written as null in the json, then None gets appended to the list as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following scheme:

```
result = []                    # resulting list

# read file, get lists
for lst in lists:
    # get your "attributes" from current list
    for value in attributes:
        if value:                  # if value != None
            result.append(value)

# result contains required values
print result
```

Comment: you ignored none values in your code , but I want to save it to the list

Comment: @AliAlgarni you can collect them into another list, for example, `result_2`.

Comment: Can you show me result2. I didn't understand. I tried to use if (line ['B'] ==None) but it didn't append empty value

Comment: @AliAlgarni try to use `if not line['B']:` instead.

Comment: I think the problem is you json is not valid. Provide your files and code, pls